# How to reset nautilus sidebar?

Tags: debian, gnome, nautilus

This is my actual problem.
[image: nome]

On mounting it gives the error :

```
couldn't find matching udev device
```

and deleting nautilus .config files, or purging nautilus, doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I have the same question... I tried to access my Google Drive, didn't like the hacky way that it tried and typically failed to connect.  Now I have this unmountable link that I cannot remove permanently in the sidebar, much like the OP with the Android links.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson found out this was a problem with the update. try apt update

Comment: Thanks, @Kushagra , but I already tried that.  Something else is going on...